# How to combine two tables in MySQL which have only one common column and other are different?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables,

Table1:

```
 Date  | Amt | Name
====================
2/5/15 | 100 | abc
--------------------
3/5/15 | 150 | xyz
--------------------
3/5/15 | 170 | pqr
--------------------
5/5/15 | 190 | zzz
--------------------
```

Table2:

```
 Date  | Amt1 | Name1
====================
2/5/15 | 130 | www
--------------------
3/5/15 | 110 | eee
--------------------
5/5/15 | 180 | rrr
--------------------
```

My output Should be:

```
 Date  | Amt | Name | amt1 | Name1
=====================================
2/5/15 | 100 | abc  | 130  | www
-------------------------------------
3/5/15 | 150 | xyz  | 110  | eee
-------------------------------------
3/5/15 | 170 | pqr  |   -  | -  
-------------------------------------
4/5/15 | 190 | zzz  |   -  | -
-------------------------------------
5/5/15 | -   | -    | 180  | rrr
-------------------------------------
```

Here Date is common field, So how can i fulfill this using MySQL query?
I have heard about FULL OUTER JOIN....But how it is implement in MySQL?

Comment: Simple `FULL JOIN` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the `LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN`, then combine them using `UNION ALL`. See my query below:

```
SELECT A.Date,Amt,Name,Amt1,Name1 FROM Table1 A LEFT JOIN Table2 B ON A.Date=B.Date
UNION ALL
SELECT B.Date,Amt,Name,Amt1,Name1 FROM Table1 A RIGHT JOIN Table2 B ON A.Date=B.Date
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JOIN` to combine two table to get this result

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 
FULL OUTER JOIN table2
ON table1.Date=table2.Date;
```

Comment: I am new in sql, so can u please write one example for achieving this?

Comment: added sample sql query in the answer, you can add column names

Comment: FULL OUTER JOIN is not supported in MySQL, So is there any other way?

Comment: in that case Left join and Right Join along with UNION ALL will solve your purpose as mentioned by @Rigel1121

Answer (score 0):

Use outer join would work for your case:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
FULL OUTER JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name;
```

Comment: OUTER JOIN is not supported? So how can i implement it in sql?

Comment: Agree with Rigel1121.